# Gracefully access memory that may not be there

Tags: c, microcontroller, c99

I am working with an arduino like microcontroller (ARM instruction set) that has some non-contiguous 32 bit memory mapped registers (Control/Status Registers, CSRs) like this:

```
#define Comparator0_CSR0  0xA000
(No 0xA004 register)
#define Comparator0_CSR2  0xA008
#define Comparator0_CSR3  0xA00C

#define Comparator1_CSR0  0xB000
#define Comparator1_CSR1  0xB004
(No 0xB008 register)
#define Comparator1_CSR3  0xB00C
.... on and on, the 0xF000 field ranges from 0x3000-0xD000, the 0xF field ranges from 0>0xC in steps of 0x4 (32b)
```

I am trying to debug some code and need to read this entire memory region from 0x3000 to 0xD00C into persistent storage that I can read when the device is crashed (that's what the read_and_store(register_address) function does).

I unfortunately have very limited code space left and cannot write a long code that would read every register independently (Believe me, I tried, example below)

I have come up with this as a reasonable loop based possible solution (does not work for reasons described below) that fits in the code space:

```
for(int i=3;i<=0xD;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=0x10;j+=4)
    {
        read_and_store_register((0x1000 * i) + (0x4 * j))
    }
}
```

but I am obviously reading through memory that does not exist and that is crashing my device. Is there some way for me to read this memory safely by either checking if it exists before reading or something else?

---

Trying to read all registers in one code block uses more code space than I have:

```
{    
    read_and_store_register(Comparator0_CSR0)
    read_and_store_register(Comparator0_CSR2)
    read_and_store_register(Comparator0_CSR3)
    read_and_store_register(Comparator1_CSR0)    
    ....
}
```

so I need some sort of a controlled loop.

I also wondered if I could potentially #define all the register names as macros, and do some sort of read(0) in the macro for the ones that dont have a real register associated with them and then do this:

```
#define COMP_NAME(x,y) Comparator##x##CSR##y
for(int i=3;i<=0xD;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=0x4;j+=1)
    {
        read_and_store_register(COMP_NAME(i,j))
    }
}
```

But apparently that's not how the x##y##z Macro works (it tries to read a register literally named COMPARATORiCSRj which is not at all what I want)

---

If the answer is reasonably no, I will accept that answer. But I feel like I have to ask. Thank you for your time.

Comment: How many registers do you want to read and what does `read_and_store_register` do? Maybe you can define a constant array that contains all register addresses and loop over the array?

Comment: (0xD-0x3)*4=40, in this example, but the question exists irrespective of the number I need to read.
Read_and_store copies the memory to a persistent storage system that I can read when the device is crashed, I have edited the question accordingly, thank you.

Comment: If the CPU raises an interrupt on invalid access then there is a possibility of using an ISR to abort that particular call to read / store and nudge the for loop along.

Comment: You'll have to research what your particular device provides as far as ways to test whether a particular register exists, or how to recover if it doesn't.  There's no generic answer to this question - the C language itself certainly hasn't got anything like this concept.  So in order to get an answer you'll have to be a lot more specific as to your device, compiler, environment, etc (and please tag accordingly).

Comment: Seems to me that Bodo's suggestion of an array would take a maximum of `(0xd - 0x3 + 1) * 4 * 2 bytes = 88 bytes`.  And then you can write a small and simple loop that iterates over the array.  Alternatively, you could have an array of the registers that *don't* exist, looping over the whole set and skipping each one that's in the array.  If the array is in sorted order then this is not hard either.

Comment: By the way, your first loop will also access registers such as `0x3010` which it sounds like was not what you wanted?  Perhaps that is part of the problem.

Comment: dependin g on what you mean by does not exist, the logic may cause a fault for addresses spaces that are not defined within the system.  Sometimes it wraps, sometimes it cause a fault and that is what it is, the programming language, etc cant fix it, not accessing it is the only way to fix this type of problem.  If that is what you are talking about

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some way for me to read this memory safely by either checking if it exists before reading or something else?

The C language does not define any such facility.  The C language also does not define any mechanism for reading objects that exist outside the scope of the program.  Programs that must do so -- typically in a freestanding C implementation -- rely on the provisions of their particular implementation and execution environment to do that.  It is conceivable that your implementation provides a for-purpose mechanism for doing what you ask, but I wouldn't bet on it.

I like @Bodo's suggestion in comments to create a table of the register addresses and loop over that, instead of probing a whole contiguous range of the address space.  That way you could avoid trying to read invalid addresses, while reducing the size of your code (+ data) somewhat.  Alternatively, you might be able reduce code by looping over contiguous ranges of registers instead of having a separate function / macro call to read each one.  There may be other approaches if you want to write some part of your code in assembly.

But again, no, the C language does not define a way to check in advance whether a memory access would be valid, nor to recover from whatever might happen in the event of an invalid access.